# Is there a way to run a program in Eclipse without it creating certain variables again every time I run the program?

Tags: java, eclipse

Basically, I would like to create a "library" of sorts in another class that is created when I run the program's main class the first time. But instead of repeating the action when I click run for a second time, I want the manipulated library in the first run to be initialized. For example if I have a static array with capacity 5 and put the int 1 in index 0, the next time I run the entire thing, I want to *start* with a static array with 1 in index 0. Is this even possible (in Eclipse) and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: Use a database and load it on start up.

Comment: Save the state values in an external file or database, then read that file when you start the program. When you terminate the program, it should write the current state to that file.

Comment: Thank you both, I'm kind of just getting started into Java and I really appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

All of your program's variables and other state are discarded when it is terminated and reinitialized when it is launched again. (This is a common cause of bugs in Android apps, which are frequently discarded and then re-opened.) To save state between program runs, you need to store it in some place that's intended for this. Common choices include files, databases (H2 with a file-backed database might be a good option), Android `SharedPreferences`, servers, and more exotic tools such as [prevalent systems](http://prevayler.org/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Java.